# I cannot find the following integral in an integral table.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

In the appendix A of [this paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/97JC00441/full) there is an integral that the author says can be solved using any good integral table. However I cannot seem to find it on any integral table (ex: gradshteyn and ryzhik) - although it could be that I am not using the table properly as it is the first time I am doing it. I have solved it using Wolfram but it does not give the same result as in the paper.

The integral is:

$$\int{\frac{-1}{1-F \cdot\text{sech}^2(x)}dx}$$

Note that the author gives the result for F < 1 which is what I want. Maybe that is why the wolfram solution is different, I am not sure.

Comment: Why is the tag "definite-integrals" when the integral is indefinite?

Comment: @user2345215, I changed it unless it ends up the OP meant for the integral to be definite.

Comment: @user2345215 my bad, thanks hayden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factor $-\dfrac1F$ outside the integral sign. Then, since $F<1$, it follows that the $\dfrac1F$ in the integrand's

denominator can be written as $1+a^2$. At the same time, similarly to $\sec^2x=1+\tan^2x$ which

we know to hold for its trigonometric counterpart, we also have $\text{sech}^2x=1-\tanh^2x$, making

our integral $\displaystyle-\frac1F\int\frac{dx}{a^2+\tanh^2x}$ . At this point we recognize $\arctan't=\dfrac1{1+t^2}$ . Substituting

$u=\dfrac{\tanh x}a$, we finally arrive at the desired result, $-I=x+\dfrac1a\arctan\dfrac{\tanh x}a$.

Comment: Truly Beautiful. The only thing that I missed when enunciating the problem was that F is actually 0 < F < 1, not just F < 1, making this solution possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If we put $x=\log t$ we have:
$$\int \frac{dx}{1-\frac{F}{\cosh^2 x}} = \int\frac{(t^2+1)^2 dt}{t^5+(2-4F)t^3+t},$$
and by putting $t=\sqrt{u}$ we get:
$$\int \frac{dx}{1-\frac{F}{\cosh^2 x}} = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(u+1)^2 du}{u^3+(2-4F)u^2+u}.$$
Decomposing the last integrand function in simple fractions leads to the answer.